# Why is scipy.stats.uniform.pdf so slow?

Tags: python, performance, scipy

`scipy.stats.uniform.pdf` is very slow.  The underlying function is very simple: return a constant if the input is within the bounds and zero if it is not.

There are many ways to implement this.  In addition to the calculation there is some overhead associated with `scipy.stats.rv_continuous`.  It allocates the output array, does some error checking, etc.  What I don't understand is that `numpy.ufunc`s do nearly the exact same thing.

**What makes the `scipy.stats` overhead so much slower than `numpy`'s
?**

### The data

As an example, here are five implementations (code below) timed with IPython's `%timeit` magic.

1. just call it!  `(73.7 µs ± 1.27 µs)`
2. make a frozen instance of `uniform` and call that.  `(76.3 µs ± 591 ns)`
3. use an if statement to check if input is "in bounds".  `(153 ns ± 1.3 ns)`
4. sum two `numpy.heaviside` calls.  `(2.6 µs ± 28.6 ns)`
5. use a `numpy.piecewise` function.  `(7.04 µs ± 30.3 ns)`

It makes sense that the direct check is fastest.  What surprises me is how much slower the `scipy` implementations are than `numpy`.

### The code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

L = -3  # location
S = 5  # scale
x = 0.0  # data point

# method 1 (just call it)
%timeit stats.uniform.pdf(x, loc=L, scale=S)

# method 2 (frozen)
frz_uni = stats.uniform(loc=L, scale=S)
%timeit frz_uni.pdf(x)

# method 3 (if)
def uni_from_if(x, loc=0, scale=1):
    if x < loc or x > loc+scale:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 / scale
%timeit uni_from_if(x, loc=L, scale=S)

# method 4 (Heaviside)
def uni_from_H(x, loc=0, scale=1):
    return np.heaviside(x-loc, 1) - np.heaviside(x-(loc+scale), 0)
%timeit uni_from_H(x, loc=L, scale=S)

# method 5 (piecewise)
def uni_piecewise(x, loc=0, scale=1):
    return np.piecewise(
        x,
        [x < loc, x > loc+scale],
        [0, 0, 1/scale]
    )
%timeit uni_piecewise(x, loc=L, scale=S)
```

Comment: I've clarified my question that to directly state that I am interested in speed differences between SciPy's overhead and NumPy's.

Answer (score 1):

When using `scipy.stats.uniform.pdf` for this task its like using shovel to put sugar in your tea :)

This function was not meant to be super performant for such easy, single-point task. Look at the implementation inside, how many things are being done:

```
# NOTE: THIS IS SCIPY CODE, NOT MINE, SO I HAVE TO PUT LICENSE BELOW...
def pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds):
    """
    Probability density function at x of the given RV.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like
        quantiles
    arg1, arg2, arg3,... : array_like
        The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the
        instance object for more information)
    loc : array_like, optional
        location parameter (default=0)
    scale : array_like, optional
        scale parameter (default=1)

    Returns
    -------
    pdf : ndarray
        Probability density function evaluated at x

    """
    args, loc, scale = self._parse_args(*args, **kwds)
    x, loc, scale = map(asarray, (x, loc, scale))
    args = tuple(map(asarray, args))
    dtyp = np.find_common_type([x.dtype, np.float64], [])
    x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)
    cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
    cond1 = self._support_mask(x, *args) & (scale > 0)
    cond = cond0 & cond1
    output = zeros(shape(cond), dtyp)
    putmask(output, (1-cond0)+np.isnan(x), self.badvalue)
    if np.any(cond):
        goodargs = argsreduce(cond, *((x,)+args+(scale,)))
        scale, goodargs = goodargs[-1], goodargs[:-1]
        place(output, cond, self._pdf(*goodargs) / scale)
    if output.ndim == 0:
        return output[()]
    return output
```

You would see that it will get better  for large `x` variable (compared to pure-python method). Still, `numpy` solution in such case would be the best.

```
Copyright (c) 2001-2002 Enthought, Inc.  2003-2019, SciPy Developers.
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
are met:

1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
   copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
   disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
   with the distribution.

3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its
   contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
   from this software without specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
"AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
(INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```